# Knockout: Select all checkboxes not working

Tags: knockout.js

We are facing a particular problem. We have a table where each row is selectable and bound with knockout, as the following:

```
thead
  tr
    th: input(type="checkbox", data-bind="checked: $root.onSelectAll")
    ..
    ..
tbody(data-bind="foreach: items")
  tr
    td
      input(type="checkbox", data-bind="attr: { value: $data.id }, checked: $root.selectedItems")
    ..
    ..
```

This works fine, as we select a item and it's id attribute is added to the selectedItems list.

We now need to implement a select all option for each page, since there's pagination. We were looking at http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/kXYuU/ but could not make it work and that's the problem. I was able to write a solution on my own, but it got much more complex than it should be. With Knockout it should be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Can you maybe share the solution what you already have? It would really help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, I could be wrong, but I don't think you can use `$root` outside the context of a `foreach` binding. Whether you can or not, you don't need it on your binding for your `th` (`$root.onSelectAll` --> `onSelectAll`).

Second, `$root.selectedItems` feels like an observableArray, you can't bind an observableArray to `checked`, it must be an observable.